# /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/keytool: No such file or directory

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

i deleted $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool accidently. Now when i run

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

i get the error above. How can i create a new one or solve this issue, thank you

Comment: where is that error log

Comment: Hi, the error is displayed in terminal after i enter the command  $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

Comment: What @Balasubramanian meant. Where is the error text in your question. You mention it `i get the error avove`. But you missed to include that error test. If it's `command not found` then reinstalling your Java version (would be the simplest).

Comment: Reinstall the JVM.